# Fullcalendar superpose events

Tags: javascript, html, css, calendar, fullcalendar

I use the FullCalendar library, and I can't find how to force FullCalendar to not superpose events (because some text can't be seen otherwise)

Here is my calendar :

[image: Events]

Comment: I don't think you can do this with CSS because fullcalendar uses absolute positioning on the events. Also, after breezing over the [event rendering](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/) documentation, it looks like coloring is the only thing you can modify.

Comment: So I have to modify the library itself I think, I will post the patch here when it's done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The patch is very simple :

```
diff --git a/src/agenda/AgendaEventRenderer.js b/src/agenda/AgendaEventRenderer.js
index 9e7243b..8b0ec63 100644
--- a/src/agenda/AgendaEventRenderer.js
+++ b/src/agenda/AgendaEventRenderer.js
@@ -182,7 +182,7 @@ function AgendaEventRenderer() {
            leftmost = colContentLeft(colI*dis + dit);
            availWidth = colContentRight(colI*dis + dit) - leftmost;
            availWidth = Math.min(availWidth-6, availWidth*.95); // TODO: move this to CSS
-           if (levelI) {
+           if (true) { // PATCH : Always render indented events
                // indented and thin
                outerWidth = availWidth / (levelI + forward + 1);
            }else{
```

It looks like that now :

[image: Agenda]